# Seleccionar página activa con javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo este código para seleccionar la página activa. Si tengo dos menús en la página solo selecciona en un menú. Si pongo el [0] selecciona el primero; si pongo el [1](https://www.fibrart.eu/albergue/primera.html) entonces me selecciona el elemento del segundo, el de abajo. Aquí no se ve bien porque ha de trabajar en la barra de direcciones. Lo he resuelto duplicando el código y, en el segundo, poniendo [1](https://www.fibrart.eu/albergue/primera.html), pero no sé si es correcto y óptimo o se puede mejorar. He probado con iteraciones, pero no lo consigo.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Caminante.

[Seleccionar página activa en menú](https://www.fibrart.eu/albergue/primera.html)

```js
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var elem_activo = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="' + location.pathname.split("/")[2] + '"]')[0];
    elem_activo.className = elem_activo.className+"seleccionado";
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(182, 19, 101, 0.9);
  font-family: "ubuntu", sans-serif; }
    
.seleccionado {
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px; }

nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid crimson;
  background-color: #f781bc;
  width: 90%;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav a {
  font-family: "ubuntu_cond", "verlag", "yanone", "yanone-Light", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dc143c;
  margin: 0 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<html xml:lang="es" lang="es-es">
<head>
<title>Prueba</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="wrapper">
<main class="portada">
    <nav>
      <a href="prueba.html">Inicio</a>
      <a href="primera.html">Primera</a>
      <a href="segunda.html">Segunda</a>
      <a href="tercera.html">Tercera</a>
      <a href="final.html">Final</a>
    </nav>
</main>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<footer>
    <nav>
      <a href="prueba.html">Inicio</a>
      <a href="primera.html">Primera</a>
      <a href="segunda.html">Segunda</a>
      <a href="tercera.html">Tercera</a>
      <a href="final.html">Final</a>
    </nav>
</footer>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="active.js">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mi principal pregunta es... por qué tienes dos menús iguales?

Comment: Entiendo que quieras tener 2 menús, pero suena ilógico marcar "activo" solo uno de ellos, cuando la página activa es la misma para ambos. Si estoy en "primera", debería marcarse ambos cierto? Segundo, si tienes 2 navs, por que no asignarles un id a ambos, y en el  codigo activar ambos ?

Comment: En realidad es un tema de investigar mis límites.
Tengo un menú que se esconde y otro que está fijo abajo.
La opción que tengo es colocar una clase en el menú de la propia página -en ambos menús- y ya está. Pero me ha resultado llamativo que, con el script solo seleccione el primero o el segundo según el número que ponga. Quería saber si hay alguna opción de programación para que actúe en ambos. 
La otra opción es juntar los dos scripts y ya está. Pero quería saber si se pueden hacer con uno solo.

Gracias, Benito y Excorpion.

Comment: Con un solo script, puedes pintar ambos, solo el de arriba, solo el de abajo, etc. Te dejaré un ejemplo de como hacer ambos, pero para pintar o uno, o el otro, debes asignar una id a los nav, y luego verificar si dentro de ellos, existe un <a> activo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segunda respuesta solicitada por Caminante.

En este caso, haremos 3 menús (cosa super innecesaria), y analizaremos cuál de las 3 secciones, es donde estamos haciendo click, y dentro de esa sección, que página es la que queremos ir.

De este modo, si solo hacemos click a el footer por ejemplo, solo debiese pintar el link del footer.

**NOTA*** *No quiero simplemente regalarte las soluciones, quiero que busques como hacer lo que falta tú, en este ejemplo faltará identificar apropiadamente la sección, mi código es una simulación que debes completar.*

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  var seccion = "main"; //Acá es donde debes obtener la sección.
  var paginaActual = "segunda.html"; //Ya sabemos que obtienes bien la ubicación con location.pathname.split("/")[2]

  var elementosActivosHeader = document.querySelectorAll(seccion +' nav a[href="' + paginaActual + '"]');

  if (elementosActivosHeader.length > 0) {
    elementosActivosHeader.forEach(function(elemento) {
      elemento.classList.add("seleccionado");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.seleccionado {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="prueba.html">Inicio</a>
    <a href="primera.html">Primera</a>
    <a href="segunda.html">Segunda</a>
    <a href="tercera.html">Tercera</a>
    <a href="final.html">Final</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<br>
<main class="portada">
  <nav>
    <a href="prueba.html">Inicio</a>
    <a href="primera.html">Primera</a>
    <a href="segunda.html">Segunda</a>
    <a href="tercera.html">Tercera</a>
    <a href="final.html">Final</a>
  </nav>
</main>
<br>
<footer>
  <nav>
    <a href="prueba.html">Inicio</a>
    <a href="primera.html">Primera</a>
    <a href="segunda.html">Segunda</a>
    <a href="tercera.html">Tercera</a>
    <a href="final.html">Final</a>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: Si más tarde, no logras obtener dinámicamente el valor de sección y modificar el javascript. Genera una nueva pregunta, para ver que has intentado hacer, averiguado, etc. Pero mi primera respuesta, si responde a tu primera pregunta.

Comment: Gracias Excorpion:
   Ya he abierto camino por closest() y me funciona bien para la url con carpeta y la del subdominio. 
   Saludos y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta para dejar solucionada la publicación

Answer (score 0):

Como dije anteriormente, lo más lógico sería marcar ambos links activos.

 Por eso te dejaré el ejemplo abajo. (el ejemplo simula un elemento activo)

Ahora, tu quieres seleccionar o uno, o el otro. Para ello realizamos una modificación solamente al javascript.

Como menciono dentro del fragmento, podemos validar cual se pinta con un if, else if, etc. Depende de que selección quieras hacer. En tu caso podemos agregar que identifique si el elemento seleccionado es del nav superior o inferior.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    // Simulando que la página actual es "primera.html"
    var paginaActual = "segunda.html";

        //Seleccionamos los elementos DENTRO de su respectiva seccion
    var elementosActivosSuperior = document.querySelectorAll('main nav a[href="' + paginaActual + '"]');
    var elementosActivosInferior = document.querySelectorAll('footer nav a[href="' + paginaActual + '"]');

    //Podemos controlar que elemento pintar, utilizando las validaciones. Esta pinta ambos, pero podemos hacer un else if, si queremos que pinte uno u otro.
    if (elementosActivosSuperior.length > 0) {
        elementosActivosSuperior.forEach(function(elemento) {
            elemento.classList.add("seleccionado");
        });
    } 
    if (elementosActivosInferior.length > 0) {
        elementosActivosInferior.forEach(function(elemento) {
            elemento.classList.add("seleccionado");
        });
    }
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    //Simulamos el elemento activo - se reemplaza por location.pathname.split("/")[2]
    var paginaActual = "primera.html"; 
    //Obtenemos los elementos
    var elementosActivos = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="' + paginaActual + '"]');
    //Recorremos los elementos activos, para asi marcarlos todos
    elementosActivos.forEach(function(elemento) {
        elemento.classList.add("seleccionado");
    });
});
```

```css
.seleccionado {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<main class="portada">
  <nav>
    <a href="prueba.html">Inicio</a>
    <a href="primera.html">Primera</a>
    <a href="segunda.html">Segunda</a>
    <a href="tercera.html">Tercera</a>
    <a href="final.html">Final</a>
  </nav>
</main>
<br>
<footer>
  <nav>
    <a href="prueba.html">Inicio</a>
    <a href="primera.html">Primera</a>
    <a href="segunda.html">Segunda</a>
    <a href="tercera.html">Tercera</a>
    <a href="final.html">Final</a>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: Gracias, Excorpión: Efectivamente, lo he probado y va bien. Por curiosidad, aunque ponga tres menús, marca el mismo elemento tres veces. Luego investigo si quiero que pinte uno u otro. Todo esto es por ahondar en JavaScript, que lo tengo cogido con pinzas. + Otro problema que me surgió fue el siguiente. La ruta va con una carpeta y por tanto, actúa split("/")[2]. Como he puesto un subdominio también (son dos opciones de petición), ahora el split hay que hacerlo en [1] porque no esta la carpeta en cuestión. Esto creo que tiene peor salida y he de poner los dos juntos. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Lo ideal es que si estás haciendo split de algo, lo cargues en alguna variable. De este modo puede validar fácilmente si la variable es correcta o no. Por otro lado, lo de pintar el uno y el otro, es el fragmento superior que te mencioné. Solo basta agregar que identifique si estás haciendo click en el nav del footer, o en el nav del main, y el uso de IF que deje arriba.